# What is mkvirtualenv command mean ? is it a Linux command or python command..?

Tags: python, linux, django

What is mkvirtualenv command mean ? is it a Linux command or python command..?. I am confused on the fact that is it a Linux command or python command...?

Also what is the difference between $ virtualenv foo and $ mkvirtualenv foo ? Are they both same..?

Comment: it's a linux command which is used to create virtual env. `mkvirtualenv foo` creates a new virtual env at your home directory. You may switch to that env by running `workon foo` on your linux terminal.

Comment: You have to familiar with [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) first then study the [mkvirtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Also what is the difference between $ virtualenv foo and $ mkvirtualenv foo ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### mkvirtualenv command is part of virtualenvwrapper.

The `mkvirtualenv` command will create a new `virtualenv` (virtual environment).  It gets installed as part of [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/).

#### what is virtualenvwrapper?

It is a set of extension commands for Python virtual environment management.

[Features](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#features) of `virtualenvwrapper` include:

1. Organizes all of your virtual environments in one place.
2. Wrappers for managing your virtual environments (create, delete, copy).
3. Use a single command to switch between environments.
4. Tab completion for commands that take a virtual environment as argument.
5. User-configurable hooks for all operations.
6. Plugin system for more creating sharable extensions.

Although it is used for managing a Python development workflow, `virtualenvwrapper` itself is actually not written in Python.  Most of it consists of shell functions inside shell scripts.  (the hook loader is written in Python)

It works in several shell environments for Linux, OSX, and Windows.  These include: bash, zsh, powershell, and the windows command prompt.

---

To answer the edit to your question:

`$ virtualenv foo` is the built-in way to create a virtualenv.  The command is part of virtualenv itself.  After creating the virtualenv, you must then activate it before using.

`$ mkvirtualenv foo` is another way to create a virtualenv (if you have virtualenvwrapper installed).  It adds the convenience of activating the virtualenv for you.  It also has some handy options that you may find useful.